# jQuery undetermined error with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Doing username checking while using jquery validate, but the problem come out that when user inserts an unavailable username it will display an error, once user tries another username the errors displayed are not styled with my CSS. This is the screenshot where I capture the error http://www.screencast.com/t/hQdRev1HOnh

I found that the problems are in the unhighlight function but trying my best to fix it, I am still unable to solve.

```
    <script>
                $('#reg_form').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                errorClass: 'error',
                validClass: 'valid',
                rules: {
                    reg_username: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                        remote: {
                            url: "check_username.php",
                            type: "post"
                        }
                    },
                    reg_password: {required: true, minlength: 3}
                },
                messages: {
                    reg_username: {
                        required: "Please fill in your username",
                        remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
                    }
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').append(error);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The problem is that `check_username.php` script is not called? It's seems it checks for min length only?

Comment: @Tony the script is called and working fine, i think only the CSS or jquery problem.

Comment: Sorry, can't get what is wrong. How it should look like? I see that border becomes red and then becomes black again.

Comment: post your code fiddle

Comment: @Tony that is the problem when red turn to black, suppose it will hide the black when user trying the insert another username.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA unable to post due i have another javascript plugin to run, even i post it will show nothing.

Comment: But you entered another `123456` ! It seems that this name is valid.

Comment: @Tony ya i fine, you see when i enter 123 i will come out the error, once the error come out i enter 123456, the error will become black (like not css style).

Comment: You mean that error text becomes balck for 1 or 2 seconds before disappearing?

Comment: @Tony ya, i don't know why it will become black for 1-2 seconds before disappearing.